# How to retrieve nearest place stored in mysql db using my gps location in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to pass my device's current location(latitude and longitude) into my php file from android app. Then use that php script to retrieve nearest places stored in mysql database.

I am using the Haversine formula to retrieve data from the database.

When hard code the coordinates it works, but i can't pass the coordinates from my device.

Code:

```
("SELECT id, rank_name, description, latitude, longitude, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM table_name HAVING distance < 2;");
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Edit your post to add in required code. Don't place it as a comment on someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euclidean Distance formula

(x1,y1) = your longitude and latitude
(x2,y2) = longitude and latitude in you database

distance = ((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)^0.5

Among all the distances choose the lowest one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, maybe i was not clear enough. But what i want to do is to pass the device coordinates to the sql query that retrieves the nearest place in the database.

Comment: Here is the sql query i am using: ("SELECT id, rank_name, description, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table_name HAVING distance < 2;");

Comment: Where there's ? i must put my device coordinates not hard coded